Power Apps search not returning expected values
I have a search string function
Search(Filter(MyList ,City = "Chicago" ),et_searchByAddress.Text,AddressValue)

This works correctly most of the time . Howsver I am finding a few bugs where results are not found when there should be.
Example:
If I put "535" into the search box
It should return
Chicago, North 535st street, Taco Bell

However no results are returned.
However entering "123"
Returns
Chicago, 123 Main st, Pizza hut 

The SharePoint list has indexes in address and city.
The list only has 500 rows.
What would be causing this issue?
Update:
I created a Test list and the value is searchable, and returns the correct value.
This may be a SharePoint issue
Solved:
This was a source data limit issue I increased the row limit to 2,000 and the issue was solved.

what happens if you search for 535st? It may well be that the search can't process partial words, but only terms that are clearly demarcated by a space or punctuation, like 123 Main st is.

The same no results. It can find other search terms in the center. Which is why I'm confused.

are you absolutely sure that this record is in the dataset that Power App has retrieved with the filter? It look like it may not have that one.

What if you search for "Taco Bell", does it then show up?

@teylyn I am sure the data is there. I manually added a second entry with the same values.

@SamNseir If I change the search column to the "Restaurant" column.
